# how to submit app for review itunesConnect when it doesn't show prepare for submission in left pannel

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I had rejected the build(ex:V1.2.1) after the review has done as we didn't find it necessary to release it. Now I want to submit v1.2.2 build to app store but its still showing me ***"1.2.1 is ready for sale"***. I am unable to submit build 1.2.2 for review. How to fix? Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add a new version in iTunesConnect first! Go to your app in iTunesConnect and click on the "+ VERSION OR PLATFORM" button/link on the left hand side.

[image]